# Why exception objects are not defined when using a python debugger?

Tags: python

Using this example:

```
try:
    int('foo')
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

When I enter the python debugger and try to inspect error, it is not defined:

```
ipdb> error                                                                                                                                   
*** NameError: name 'error' is not defined
```

Why is this and how can I inspect it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why there is such a behavior but adding an instruction (anything) after the `ipdb.set_trace()` makes the `error` printing work. For instance:

```py
try:
    int('foo')
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
""
```

(I just added `""` at the end).
I guess `ipdb.set_trace` stops the program at the following instruction so such an instruction needs to exists, but it is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the last line of the exception
the following examples work

```
try:
      int('foo')
except ValueError as error:
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()    
    print(error)
```

or

```
try:
    int('foo')
except ValueError as error:
    print(error)
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()    
    print("")
```